# Android kernel decompiling?

Tags: kernel

I want to decompile kernel to add features like OC. I extracted ram disk, dts (device tree source) and compiled kernel from boot.img. I also have other files like recovery, system, data, etc. How to decompile this kernel or add features other way?

Comment: Why do you need to decompile the kernel? The source is already available.

Comment: Here i manage this kernel dissembling .
http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=582284&view=findpost&p=82274775

Comment: Decompression games, `objdump` and a lot of fun cross referencing strings to identify pieces of code by what they printk()

Answer (score 2):

I am bit confused, why do you want to decomplie something that is open source? You only need to grab the kernel sources, make your edits and compile it for your device.

Here some links to get you started:

- [Setup the build environment](https://source.android.com/source/building.html)
- [Building Kernels](https://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html)
- [Kernel Source Repository](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/)

Comment: This answer is a bit naive.  While all vendors of a Linux kernel (Android or otherwise) gain the right to distribute copies *only* by agreeing to provide complete corresponding source, that sadly doesn't always mean that they *will*.  With a few leading brand exceptions, generic sources won't typically work on the physical device in front of you, and even to the degree that they might it is sometimes necessary to take apart the existing binary kernel to figure out how to adapt and configure generic sources to work on the hardware.